# List[Map[Int,Object]] sorting

Tags: scala

Hi I am new in scala and I don't know how to change following code:

```
def makeProfil(listProfils: List[Profil]): List[Profil] ={

   // var newList = List[Profil]
          var ll = List[Map[Int,Profil]]()
   listProfils.foreach( item => {

     var count = item.czasOgladania.get
     if(item.czyKupil.get) count = count *4 ;
     if(item.czyPrzeczytal.get) count = count *3 ;
     if(item.czyWKarcie.get) count = count *2 ;
     ll ::= Map (count -> item) 
   } )

  }
```

I want to  sort **ll** list by element **count** from and return sorted List[Profil] as the result. I tried various things but none of them work good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` has a method, `sortWith`, which sorts your list, where you can provide the criteria for sorting the list. The criteria is a function, accepting two arguments (two profiles), and result is Boolean, which indicates which one of them is "greater".

So, you can do the following:

```
ll.sortWith((p1, p2) => 
  getCount(p1) > getCount(p2)
)
```

where

```
def getCount(profil: Profil) = {
  var count = profil.czasOgladania.get
  if(profil.czyKupil.get) count = count *4 ;
  if(profil.czyPrzeczytal.get) count = count *3 ;
  if(profil.czyWKarcie.get) count = count *2 ;
  count
}
```

**Update**

BTW, it seems that `profil.czasOgladania`, `profil.czyKupil` etc., are `Option`s. In that case you should first check if they are defined, and than perform computations. You may define default values, e.g.

```
// if profil.czasOgladania is defined, get the value. Else, return 10.
val count = profil.czasOgladania.getOrElse(10)
```

or:

```
if(profil.czyWKarcie.getOrElse(false)) count = count *2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the whole thing without any mutable states (vars are bad practice).  First you map the list of profiles to a list of (count, profile) tuples.  The map doesn't seem necessary.  Then you sort the list by the first item in the tuple, then map it to a list of profiles (the second item in the tuple).

```
def makeProfil(listProfils: List[Profil]): List[Profil] ={

    val profileCounts = listProfils.map( item => {
         val count = item.czasOgladania.getOrElse(0)
         val kupil = if(item.czyKupil.isDefined) 4 else 1
         val przeczytal = if(item.czyPrzeczytal.isDefined) 3 else 1;
         val wKarcie = if(item.czyWKarcie.isDefined) 2 else 1 ;
         val finalCount = count * kupil * przeczytal * wKarcie
         (count, item) 
    } )
    profileCounts.sortBy( _._1).map(_._2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sortBy`:

```
def makeProfil(listProfils: List[Profil]): List[Profil] = {
  def getCount(profil: Profil) = {
    var count = profil.czasOgladania.get
    if (profil.czyKupil.get) count *= 4
    if (profil.czyPrzeczytal.get) count *= 3
    if (profil.czyWKarcie.get) count *= 2
    count
  }

  listProfils.sortBy(p => getCount(p))
}
```